# Fantasy series a boy who finds a magic ring which allows him to find other rings

Tags: story-identification, books

Okay, first up, this series is something I read approximately 20 years ago (late 1990s to early 2000s), so my details may not be 100% accurate. It’s a medieval type fantasy setting.

Here’s what I remember:

- Main character is a boy who finds a magical ring (I think in a well). The ring gives him the ability to ‘seek’ out other rings (I think). I’m pretty sure he was an orphan and possibly indentured? We didn’t know he was the hero of the story at the beginning.
- He meets with a company (at the same time he stumbles upon the ring) of men who are fighting to overthrow evil rulers. They may also have been looking for the rings. They may have met at an inn?
- There are two evil warlords, brothers, who can shapeshift into wolves (black and white). One of the companions kills the white shapeshifter and puts its fur on his shield. The fur enchants his shield so it protects him. I believe he ends up a bearer of a magical ring. I think his name started with D. It was a weird name with another letter directly after the D, like Dh or Df.
- Another ring bearer is granted the ability to heal. His name starts with a R, and is possibly Rafe, or Ralf
- One ring bearer is granted the gift of invisibility. During the series he falls in a magic river and becomes immortal. I think his name started with L (Leith? Leaf?)
- The main character turns out to be the last of a race of good/white/light people. Basically a people who always fight on the side of the light. I think they rode/worked with unicorns? We don’t learn this until the end of the original trilogy, I believe.
- The next series in the same world by the author starts with someone hunting down all the remaining ring bearers years and years later and killing all but the immortal one. I didn’t read beyond that point though. Sorry.
- The first trilogy ends with a face off with the evil Goddess She. Possibly a Goddess of Chaos. The main character sacrifices himself and is frozen in a fountain with her.
- I feel like there was at least 3 books in the initial series. I remember one of the books was purple. I don’t know if they were new at the time of reading as my mother purchased them. They were all in English.
- I’m positive that the the new series starring the immortal (after the trilogy I am looking for) was released around 18-20 years ago. I think it’s blurb even said "after *main protagonist* sacrifices himself to defeat the goddess She..." I don’t know how many books there were in this series as I stopped reading them.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00P9CP7XE/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_ep_dp_uqctAbESDW29D sounds vaguely similar.

Comment: No, sorry. The book I’m looking for is medieval fantasy, no cars or modern tech involved. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: Aw, just looking at the title I thought I'd nail this one easy...

Comment: So the goddess is named "She"?

Comment: So I guess this is not The Lord of the Rings story about rings.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you here, never heard about fantasy books involving magic rings. ;-)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots As far as I remember, yes. The Goddess isn’t a foe until the last book in the first trilogy (I think it was a trilogy, there were definitely 3 books for the first saga minimum).

Comment: @Legoman Definitely not. The only similarity is the fact that there is multiple rings as part of the lore.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Well it looks like this question also will help someone else [here](https://www.nypl.org/blog/2017/11/22/finding-book-forgotten-title?page=1#comment-54643), assuming my comment there goes through.

Answer (score 7):

I've been trying to find the name of this series of books too! And I found it!

*Chronicles of the Custodians* by Martin Middleton

- [*Circle of light*](https://www.qbd.com.au/chronicles-of-the-custodians-1-circle-of-light/martin-middleton/9780330271509/)
- *Triad of Darkness*
- *Sphere of Influence*
- *The New Age*
- *The New Order*
- *The New Dawn*

Summary of the first book:

> The King of Nuevah is dead, murdered by his own brother. Evil forces threaten to plunge Nuevah into Darkness...unless a lost prince - ambushed and sold into slavery years before - returns to claim his rightful throne.
>   Four Vahian soldiers embark on an epic journey in search of the lost prince. They are joined by a young bondservant called Teal, whose instinctive skill with weapons reveals the mystery of his birthright. Teal finds a ring in the subterranean city of Perdu which gives him mystic powers and enables him to draw together others with identical rings and similar abilities. Under Teal's guidence [sic], the seven Usare must use the combined might of the rings to form a Circle of Light against the forces of darkness who threaten to engulf all the lands in war.
>
> Teal's perilous odyssey leads the Usare across many strange lands and sets them against horrifying creatures, savage foes and age-old magic. As they venture closer to the Dark Forces, Teal learns of a terrifying ancient prophecy... that he alone must fulfill.

Comment: The best story ID answers usually include a comparison showing the elements mentioned by the asker that are covered by the proposed answer; it's nice to also note any elements the asker described that *aren't* in the proposed answer, especially if you see a reason why the asker may have gotten confused.